# Connect to remote Mongodb server on mongoshell

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I started using mongoshell to connect to my remote mongodb using the following:

**connect (" connectionstring with username and login info")**

I saw this was method I saw on mongodb documentation used for windows mongoshell and wanted to confirm I was doing this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

the reference:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/connect/#example

```
db = connect("remote_ip:27017/myDatabase")
```

Comment: It is not local database it is remote